# Invalid argument type :MKAnnotationView to unary expression

Tags: objective-c

```
#import "ViewController7.h"

@interface ViewController7 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController7
@synthesize myMap;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

-(MKAnnotationView *)myMap:(MKMapView *)myMap viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =
[myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifiere:@"pinView"];


    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
 initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
        pinView.pinColor= MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}

[self GUmap];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void) GUmap
{
myMap.mapType= MKMapTypeStandard;
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center.latitude= 000000;
newRegion.center.longitude= 00000;
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta= 000000;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta= 000000;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude= 00000;
coordinate.longitude= 0000000;

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
[annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
[annotation setTitle:@"HI"];
[annotation setSubtitle:@"Welcome!!"];
[self.myMap removeAnnotations:self.myMap.annotations];
[self.myMap addAnnotation:annotation];

[self.myMap setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

}




@end
```

everything is working fine except the code -(MKAnnotationView *)myMap
it's giving me the error (Invalid argument type :MKAnnotationView to unary expression) 
I tried everything but nothing worked 
any help please... Thank you

Comment: Now you head over to Google and search for "beginner Objective-C tutorial".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First issue** is that the code for the `viewForAnnotation` method is *inside* the `viewDidLoad` method.  That's the reason for the "invalid argument type...unary expression" error -- the compiler is confused.

Move the `viewForAnnotation` method outside of `viewDidLoad`.

**Second issue** you will get after fixing the first one is that `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifiere` is the wrong method name.  It should be `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` (no `e` at the end).

**Third issue** you will get after fixing the first two is that the name of the `viewForAnnotation` method is wrong.  Right now, it's `myMap:viewForAnnotation:`.  The delegate method must be named `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.  You can change the name of the internal parameters but not the public part.  If you don't change the name, the map view will not call your method.

**Final issue** (maybe) I should point out is that you may want to put an actual latitude and longitude and a non-zero span otherwise your annotation will be in the Atlantic Ocean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to put your `myMap:viewForAnnotation:` method inside your `viewDidLoad` method. Don't do that.

It should be:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)myMap:(MKMapView *)myMap viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =
[myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifiere:@"pinView"];


    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
 initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
        pinView.pinColor= MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [self GUmap];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```